# Java String array not working. Code included

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int LENGTH=0;
    int currentSize=0;
    String[] albumArray = new String[LENGTH];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many tracks are in your album?");
    LENGTH=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Thanks.");
    System.out.println("Please enter " + LENGTH + " track names to add to the album: ");

    //Prompts user to enter values until the array is filled. Repeats until filled.
    while (currentSize < LENGTH){
        System.out.print("Enter track name "+(currentSize+1)+":\t");
        albumArray[currentSize] = sc.nextLine();
        currentSize++;
    }

    for (int i =0; i<LENGTH;i++){
        System.out.println(albumArray[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

Okay, so basically this program allows the user to create an album. The user sets the number of tracks (LENGTH) in the array, and then assigns a String value to each index in the array.

I'm getting an error under line 18

`"albumArray[currentSize] = sc.nextLine();"`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you include what error you get

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: i believe one of your problem is you are creating 0 lenght array, and then you are trying to add items to it

Comment: String[] albumArray = new String[LENGTH]; put this line after taking length

Comment: Sorry. This is the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at AlbumCreatorArray.main(AlbumCreatorArray.java:18)"

Comment: On a slightly different note: please adhere to naming conventions. `LENGTH` should instead be called `length` as it is not a constant as the all uppcase spelling would suggest.

Comment: The computer runs your code in order from top to bottom, except when otherwise specified. So it creates an array with `LENGTH` elements (i.e. 0 elements because LENGTH contains 0), then it asks the user for the length.

Answer (score 5):

```
int LENGTH=0;
int currentSize=0;
String[] albumArray = new String[LENGTH]; //can't do this yet, LENGTH is still 0

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many tracks are in your album?");
LENGTH=sc.nextInt();
```

You need to create the array **after** you know the length.

```
int LENGTH=0;
int currentSize=0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many tracks are in your album?");
LENGTH=sc.nextInt();
String[] albumArray = new String[LENGTH];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing albumArray as zero length. Please initialize it after taking input from user.